# php how to do 2 statements == || etc

Tags: php

Hey guys i've been changing up a few things in a script i've purchased.

The sidebar is hidden everywhere except the homepage. what i'm trying to do is that it also shows on searchresults page etc.

this is the code in my php file for the sidebar:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if(com() !== "home") {echo 'hide';} ?> animated zoomInLeft">
```

i've tried this but guess i'm doing something wrong :(

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if(com() !== "home" || "searchresults") {echo 'hide';} ?> animated zoomInLeft">
```

can someone please help me out, i am still learning and your help would be really appreciated! <3
Also what if i try to add 1 more page so home, searchresults, video for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"searchresults"  => always echo "hide"
try this

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if(!(in_array(com(),array("home","searchresults")))) {echo 'hide';} ?> animated zoomInLeft">
```

or

```
<div id="sidebar" class="<?php if((com() !== "home") || (com() !== "searchresults")) {echo 'hide';} ?> animated zoomInLeft">
```

Comment: omg that actually worked, i thought we couldn't use , like that in php.
Well guess i learned a new thing today! :D
I can't upvote your anwser since i'm new but i really appreciate u taking the time to help out Bai :D